# C++ SDL Mixer Mix_Music : incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, sdl-mixer, incomplete-type

whenever I try to create Mix_Music instance, I get this error: "incomplete type is not allowed".

However, I need to get the address of the pointer music before calling Mix_LoadMUS(file);

Code:

```
Mix_Music *music;

/* I need the memory address here */

music = Mix_LoadMUS(file);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: 1. Include the header file(s) that declares *Mix_Music* and  *Mix_LoadUS*.  2. Apparently you don't need the address of the pointer music; because you only show one function and it doesn't need the address of the pointer.  3. The code can be simplified to `Mix_Music *music = Mix_loadMUS(file);`

Comment: You are right, I don't show the whole code. The point is that I need to pass the memory address to a thread which will load the file there. So I would like to add an empty Mix_Music to some kind of a list/map and then pass memory address to thread. It's up to the thread whether it will load the file there or not. It works fine with other classes but I don't know how to do it with Mix_Music. Headers are included.

Comment: The address of "music", which is "&music",  and the address of an empty "Mix_Music" are different things. "&music" is a the address of a *pointer to nowhere* until Mix_LoadMUS() is called.  Afterward "&music" points to the address of a  newly allocated *struct _Mix_Music*.

"Mix_Music mmus;" would allocate an empty *Mix_Music* on the stack. Using *static* or *malloc()* , or *new* would put it elsewhere.   Its address would be "&mmus";  But that is the address of an arbitrary *Mix_Music,* not one from MIX_LoadMUS(). It is not a useful address, as Mix_LoadMUS() allocated its own structs.

Comment: Having *music* as a pointer in an array, means thread needs to access the
array and its index. See the updated answer; it's too much to insert
here.

Answer (score 4):

**Incomplete Type**

#include "[SDL_mixer.h](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_3.html#SEC3)" and it should be fine[1](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_3.html#SEC3),[2](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_55.html#SEC55).

The compiler is not capable of compiling SDL-related code without the SDL includes to tell it what those SDL refernces (Mix_Musi,  Mix_LoadMUS, etc) refer too. See the SDL_Mixer Tutorial at kekkai.org/roger[3](http://www.kekkai.org/roger/sdl/mixer/) It has a complete example.

[1](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_3.html#SEC3) SDL Include file
[2](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_55.html#SEC55) Mix_LOadMUS
[3](http://www.kekkai.org/roger/sdl/mixer/) SDL Tutorial with complete example

--

**Update: Using an Array of Music Items**

This is an example of how to access a particular pointer to *Mix*_ *Music* from within a thread's code, or in any place lexically separate from the allocation of the pointer variable.  An actual implementation may want to use dynamic array allocation and needs to add error handling for file-not-found or failed-to-load, etc.

MEnt.h  A common iclude file for the initilization and thread modules:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"

enum { MAXENTRIES=1024 };
struct MEnt{ 
       Mix_Music * music;
       char *filename;
};

extern MEnt Marray[MAXENTRIES];
extern int Mselected;
```

Program initialization:

```
#include "MEnt.h"

// Alocate space for array of music items

MEnt Marray[MAXENTRIES]; 
int Mselected=-1;
```

In the thread's code,include:

```
#include "MEnt.h"
// Return a pointer for the selected music item:
// Allocate new Mix_Music* if not already done,
// otherwise return the already allocated pointer.
Mix_Music *getSelected(){
    Mix_Music *music;

    if(Mselected >= 0 && Mselected < MAXENTRIES){
      struct MEnt &current=Marray[Mselected];
       if(!(music=current.music) &&
                  (current.filename!=NULL))
          music=current.music=
                  Mix_LoadMUS(current.filename);
    }
    return music;
}
```